# Using Javascript to Append Text Fields

Tags: javascript

newbie here - so go easy.

I'm working on writing some javascript for a storefront that takes the standard clearing center model, turns it into two drop downs and then takes the values of those two drop downs and puts the selected values back into the text field.

I'm far from the best at javascript (as you'll likely see) but I'm trying in earnest to learn it.

My code is below, if some kind individual could point me in the right direction - I'd be hugely grateful.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery*/
/*jslint devel: true */


$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    var codes = ["TEST1", "TEST2"];
    if ($(".clearingConfigCell")) {

$('#ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_lblCostCenter').hide();
$('#ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_txtCostCenter').hide();

        $(".ClearingConfigCell").append("Please Select Cost Center Code 1: ");
        if ($(".ClearingConfigCell").length > 0) {
            $(".ClearingConfigCell").parent().append("<select id='myCCselect' class='clearingConfigCell'/><br><br>");
            $.each(codes, function (i, val) {
                $('#myCCselect').append($('<option>', {value: val, text : val }));
            });
            $("#myCCselect").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === "Please Select Cost Center Code:") {
                    $(".ClearingConfigCell").val("#myCCselect1");
                }
            });
        }
        $(".ClearingConfigCell").append("Please Select Cost Center Code 2: ");
        if ($(".ClearingConfigCell").length > 0) {
            $(".ClearingConfigCell").parent().append("<select id='myCCselect2' class='clearingConfigCell'/>");
            $.each(codes, function (i, val) {
                $('#myCCselect2').append($('<option>', {value: val, text : val }));
            });
            $("#myCCselect2").change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === "Please Select Cost Center Code:") {
                    $(".ClearingConfigCell").val("#myCCselect2");
                }
            });
        }
    }
    $(".customCostCenterField").keyup(function () {
        $("#ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_txtCostCenter").val($("#myCCselect").val() + "||" + $("#myCCselect2").val());
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I apologize for the confusion. Here is the code I'm looking to modify with the javascript. The problem I'm having is that when I submit the page data, I'm getting an error stating that the cost center hasn't been filled in, meaning that my javascript has not changed the #ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_txtCostCenter.

```
    <td class="ClearingConfigCell"><span id="ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_lblCostCenter">Cost Center:</span>
   <input name="ctl00$cphMainContent$ctlClearingUserData10005$txtCostCenter" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cphMainContent_ctlClearingUserData10005_txtCostCenter" style="width:200px;"></td>
```

Comment: 3 mins in, I'm still trying to understand the issue. Can you point out *selected values back into the text field* where in the code you do this ? Is this the issue ? What is `.ClearingConfigCell` ? input or span or div ? share the html part that is related to this function. this will help

Comment: it is very hard to understand what your code is supposed to be doing, and you haven't really asked us a question, so it is unlikely you'll get any answers. I suggest reading the jQuery docs for the `.append()` and `.val()` functions so you understand how you can use them with your elements.

Comment: Updated the ask. I apologize for the confusion. I'm new here!  As for the _selected values back into the text field_ that is the txtCostCenter input field.